# How to show the ForeignKey' content in Django template

Tags: django, templates, model, foreign-keys

I am beginner in django, there is a question i am fronting is that how to show the content of ForeignKey item, for example i have a table called company, there is a field "parentcompany" for storage the ForeignKey(UID) with the parentcompany, all the company is created on the this company table. I already been success to create this relationship, but I can not show the parentcompany's name in the template.

[image]

I already tried using this {{company.parentcompany_id.companyName}}, but nothing is shown.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
company.parentcompany.companyName
```

No need to use parentcompany_id, Django will automatically retrieve linked object.

Answer (score 0):

instead of passing **`{{company.parentcompany_id.companyName}}`** pass **`{{company.parentcompany.companyName}}`**

#### models.py

```
class ComapnyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    parentcompany = models.ForeignKey('self',on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

#### views.py

```
def DemoView(request):
  data = ComapnyModel.objects.all()
  context = {
      'data': data
  }
  return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

#### HTML code

```html
<div class="container p-5">
  <div class="row mx-auto">
    <div class="col-12">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">No.</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">E-Mail</th>
            <th scope="col">Contact</th>
            <th scope="col">Parent Company</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for i in data %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
            <td>{{i.name}}</td>
            <td>{{i.email}}</td>
            <td>{{i.contact}}</td>
            <td>
              {% if i.parentcompany %}
              {{i.parentcompany.name}}
              {% else %}
              <span><i> - </i></span>
              {% endif %}
            </td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Browser Output

[image]

Comment: Got it, it is detailed, and thank you very much!!!!